# Tricky form submission

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation

how can you submit a form by bypassing the required attribute using button 2

like i have button 2 and button 1

i want to submit form  by clicking button 2 and bypass required attribute

and both buttons must have type=submit

```html
<form method="POST">
  <input name="try" required>
  <button type="submit">button 1</button>
  <button type="submit">button 2</button>
</form>
```

Comment: so you wish to submit the form, using `button 2` but ignore the `required` attribute on the text input field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `formnovalidate`

```html
<form method="POST">
  <input name="try" required>
  <button type="submit">button 1</button>
  <button type="submit" formnovalidate>button 2</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using some simple Javascript should allow you to use button two but ignore the `required` attribute assigned to the text field.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button')[1].addEventListener('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  this.parentNode.try.required=false;
  this.parentNode.submit();
})
```

```html
<h2>submit test</h2>
        
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="try" required />
  <button type="submit">button 1</button>
  <button type="submit">button 2</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<form method="POST">
  <input name="try" required>
  <button type="submit">button 1</button>
  <button type="submit" value="ignore" >button 2</button>
</form>
```